# How to click a button in PDF form with iText?

Tags: pdf, itext

I have to fill PDF form with some data. This form contains a few tables with  "Add" button which adds new row with inputs to this table, for example to "FOREIGN PATENT DOCUMENTS".
I need to "click" this button in my code using iText a few times, add necessary rows, get input names there and fill them. How can I do this with iText? Could anybody provide me a code example?

My PDF file with form  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwtWU1543EbTQ3A3b2dZcW9qYk0

This file is predefined and I can't regenerate it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't "click" a button programmatically. You just provide the data that is necessary, and the form will adapt.

See the [FillXFA](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples-itext5/xfa-examples#1464-fillxfa.java) example. We have a [purchase_order.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/pdfs/purchase_order.pdf) that looks like this:

[image]

This document has an "Add item" button to add more line items (which results in creating more pages if necessary). That button only makes sense if there's a GUI, but when you fill out the form programmatically, there aren't any buttons to push. You just provide the XML with the data (e.g. [data.xml](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/xml/data.xml)), like this:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
            new FileOutputStream(dest));
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    XfaForm xfa = form.getXfa();
    xfa.fillXfaForm(new FileInputStream(XML));
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

The result looks like this: [purchase_order_filled.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/xfa/cmp_purchase_order_filled.pdf)

[image]

As you can see, multiple lines were added, without pushing any button.

**Important:** I see that you have a hybrid document. I think you should make it a pure XFA form. This code won't work if you keep the AcroForm fields.

Comment: How can I make a document a pure XFA form? Is it impossible to ignore existing AcroForm fields while filling data from XML?

Comment: By removing the `Fields` array from the form dictionary, and removing the widget annotations from the pages (if any; I just checked the form dictionary and to my surprise, I noticed that it contained a `Fields` array that wasn't empty; that is *extremely odd* for a dynamic form).

Comment: Your solutions is working, have similar dynamic table, filled it with data.

Comment: @nikolai.serdiuk The typical way to say that a solution is working, is to up-vote the answer.